# Why does ASP.NET Core ignore asp-action helper tag?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, razor, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-2.0

I'm getting unexpected behavior in a Core 2.0 MVC app. Check this out:

I have a controller "ProfileController.cs" with simple methods:

```cs
public async Task<IActionResult> Index()
{
    return View();
}

public async Task<IActionResult> Edit()
{
    return View();
}
```

I've got the following markup in Profile/Index.cshtml:

```html
<a asp-controller="Profile" asp-action="Edit">Edit Profile</a>
```

I'm using the following route mapping in Startup.cs:

```cs
routes.MapRoute(
    name: "default",
    template: "{controller=Home}/{action=Index}/{id?}");
```

But here is CRAZY behavior I am seeing:

The anchor tag *ALWAYS* generates and results in **`profile/index!`**  No matter what. `asp-action="Edit"` is completely ignored and results in "index" or even "index/2" if additional params are on the url.

Why?

I know my routing is working because simply entering `/profile` or `/profile/index` or `/profile/edit` renders the proper pages.

Comment: This code looks fine. Are you sure this code is causing the issue ?

Comment: No, I'm convinced I am missing something elsewhere.  But regardless, I'm not seeing how the razor engine can simply ignore the action instruction it was given. It must be doing something magical, not just applying the requested code.

Comment: I just tried the same code you have in a local project and it works fine

Comment: I've got different but similar problem. The asp-action tag will work for some methods, but not others. It just ignores the Index() method on my controller. If I rename it to IndexLOL() then it works fine.

Answer (score 1):

OK, this is half an answer. I resolved the issue, but the question of what magic the Razor engine is applying is still a mystery.

I overlooked this mistaken route applied to a POST method in the same  ProfileController mentioned above:

```
[HttpPost]
[Route("[controller]/Index")]
public async Task<IActionResult> Edit([FromForm]User m)
{
    // do stuff
    return View();
}
```

Note the **"/Index"** action applied to the method called "Edit" (oops!)

Removing/fixing that route fixed the main problem:

```cs
[HttpPost]
[Route("[controller]/Edit")]
public async Task<IActionResult> Edit([FromForm]User m)
{
    // do stuff
    return View();
}
```

BUT it still raises the question: why on earth did the Razor engine apply the wrong thing by (apparently, magically) sniffing around and looking at a POST route that has nothing to do with the action requested?  (and remember, typing `/profile/edit` into the URL worked fine, routing was working for GET despite my blunder).

Furthermore, it did not fix the issue where parameters of the current url were being applied to the path...

If I was on `/profile/index` the rendered action would be correct as `/profile/index` . But if I was on `/profile/Index/2` the rendered action would be wrong as `/profile/Index/2`.  I was NOT expecting the id to be included in the action . To correct this, I had to add **`asp-route-id=""`** as follows:

```html
<a asp-controller="Profile" asp-action="Index" asp-route-id="">View Profile</a>
```

This behavior might be by-design, but I think that magical routing issue above has to be a bug.